# Python Timeout Function

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, timeout, forecasting

I have created a forecasting program, which gets a numpy array out of python and fills this information in an interface to R.
R generates with this information a forecast. After calculation the array will be send back to python.

My Problem is that something goes wrong in the process in R and Python waits for an answer but it doesn’t come.

I want to use a Timeout, if python gets no feedback from R in 10 sec, than the forecast should be 0 or the “except loop”.

Attached is my current code. I do a jumpy for every row in which the error with no feedback happens. This technique takes too long to identify all rows with a problem...
I also use the “except loop” for errors, which occur in the program and the program can handle this problem.

```css
def r_x13(bers, fc):
    r = pr.R(RCMD='/usr/local/bin/R', use_numpy=True)
    r('library("seasonal")')
    
    if not (type(bers) is np.array):
        bers = np.array(bers)
    res = []
    start_time = time.time()
    forbidden = [23975, 24733, 24735]
    for index, ber in enumerate(bers):
        if not(index in forbidden):
            res.append(single_r_x13(ber,fc,r,index))
        else:
            res.append([np.nan] * fc)
        print("---------%s sekunden fuer Arima %s ------" % (((time.time() - start_time)/ (index + 1)), index))
    return res#np.array([single_r_x13(ber,fc,r) for ber in bers])

def single_r_x13(ber,fc,r,c):

    try:
        print ber
        r.assign("rdata%s" % c, ber)
        ts_str = "my_ts%s <- ts(rdata%s, start=c(2012, 1), end=c(2014,12), frequency=12)" % (c,c)
        r(ts_str)


        r("ar%s <- seas(my_ts%s, forecast.save = 'forecasts')" % (c,c))
        r("res%s <- series(ar%s, 'forecast.forecasts')" % (c,c))
        #print(r('res%c'))
        forecast = r.get('res%s' % c)[:, 0][:fc]
        return forecast
    except:# TypeError:
        return [np.nan]*fc
```

Comment: You might consider having R create the error message if it fails, which it promotes back to Python which then triggers an error function of some kind in the python script. You could use Boolean logic to evaluate the return value and keep running or except.

Comment: I didnt get a error message. R is running and python. R open a external software X13as. This programm does the forecast. X13as doesnt give any feedback normal takes a forecast like 1 sec. If I could use a timeout when R call this program? If something like this possible